# How to create menu and submenu using taxonomy collection in drupal commerce kickstart?

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms

I am using Drupal Commerce Kickstart for ecoomerce site. I created menu using taxonomy **collection**. I want to create submenu also using taxonomy **collection**. Is it is possble? I want to menu like this Image.[image]

I am creating taxonomy vocabulary as 'collection'.i created 'computers'. then i can add the products in computers. If i want to add the products in computers->printers. How can i create computers->printers using taxonmoy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is module [Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu). You should use [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module.

Comment: I am using that module only .Please refer the image above i have mentioned. I am creating vocabulary as 'collection'.i created 'computers'. then i can add the products in computers. If i want to add the products in computers->printers. How can i create computers->printers?

Comment: Drupal Taxonomy module provides multi level hierarchcal category system. See the Guide here - http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/drupal/drupal_taxonomy_manage_vocabulary.htm